# Input streaming data not distributed equally among tasks

Tags: java, apache-spark, task, spark-streaming

I have written spark streaming job which reads data from a s3.
The job has series of mapwithstate followed by maptopair calls, like below:

```
JavaDStream<String> cdrLines = ssc.textFileStream(cdrInputFile);
JavaDStream<CDR> cdrRecords = cdrLines.map(x -> cdrStreamParser.parse(x));
JavaDStream<CDR> cdrRecordsFiltered = cdrRecords
        .filter(t -> t != null);
JavaPairDStream<String, CDR> sTripletStream = cdrRecordsFiltered
        .mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<String, CDR>(s
                .gettNumber(), s));

JavaPairDStream<String, Tuple2<CDR, List<StatusCode>>> stateDstream1 = sTripletStream
        .mapWithState(
                StateSpec.function(hsMappingFunc).initialState(
                        tripletRDD)).mapToPair(s -> s);

JavaPairDStream<String,Tuple2<CDR,List<StatusCode>>> stateDstream2 = stateDstream1
.mapWithState(StateSpec.function(cfMappingFunc).initialState(cfHistoryRDD))
        .mapToPair(s -> s);

JavaPairDStream<String, Tuple2<CDR, List<StatusCode>>> stateDstream3 = stateDstream2
        .mapWithState(StateSpec.function(imeiMappingFunc).initialState(imeiRDD))
        .mapToPair(s -> s);
```

I have spark.default.parallelism set to 6. I see first and last maptopair stages are fast enough. The second and third maptopair stages are very slow.

Each of these stages run through 6 tasks. In the second and third maptopair stages, 5 tasks run with 2s. But one task is taking very long time ~3-4min. the shuffle data that task is very high compared to other tasks, which causing bottleneck.

Is there a way we can distrubute the load among all tasks more uniformly?

Comment: Can you explain what your code is trying to achieve? Perhaps with better context we can help formulate a better graph.

Answer (score 0):

This is use case for CDR processing. Each CDR event has these fields telno, imei, imsi, callforward, timestamp.

I maintain 3 kinds of info in spark state: 1. last know CDR event (record) for a given telephone number 2. callforward number list for each telephone 3. list of all known imei's. 
Three mapwithstate function calls corresponds to below functionality:
step1 : As the CDR events comes in, i need to do some field comparisons with last known CDR event with same telephone number. I maintain latest event for a given telno in the spark state, so that i can do field comparisons as new CDR events comes in.
step2 : For a given telno., i want to check if the callforward number is known number or not. So i need to maintain history of telno. -> list of callforward numbers in the state.
step3 : I need to maintain list of all imei numbers came across, so far in the state, so that for each imei in the CDR event, we can say if its known or new imei.